# Can windows switch between integrated and dedicated gpu without restarting an application

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, intel-graphics, discrete-graphics

I wanted to mimic Windows behavior of switching GPUs on Linux (Pop!_OS) now that it supports running certain applications on the discrete graphics card while the rest runs on the integrated one.

My question is: if a Windows application is running on integrated GPU, can it switch to the dedicated one without restarting the application if the application demands more graphics power? This is not the case in Pop_OS! since an application can either use the dedicated or integrated graphics card.

Thank you

Comment: I have seen an option to indicate which GPU to use within an application's settings, however, in every case that required the application to be restarted.  However, if it is supported, the support in order to do so would be entirely up to the developer to support it.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah you can choose which GPU you want to run the application on, but I don’t know if you can switch GPUs while using the application.

Comment: This is only a guess.. which is why it is a comment and not an answer.  The output (display) of ANYTHING in Windows is done via something called a ["Device Context"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts).. this is true for a printer or screen/gpu.  The application developer might very well be able to switch "device contexts" from the default they were handed within a single process but would need to write some fancy code to do so.  You are probably SOL on this.

Comment: I would like a way to do this, and have used the settings to prefer certain graphics devices depending on the monitor which I normally use them on, but have not found a way for this to happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I use windows 10 with a mobile 3070 and I essentially have to reboot the machine when I unplug as a fast way to make sure all applications stop using the Nvidia GPU and eat my battery in 10 minutes.

When I plug I don't bother restarting applications until I run into performance hitches etc and am motivated to restart the applications so I can have them run smoother on the dedicated GPU.